# Mui DesktopDatePicker - Show all months in mobile view

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, datepicker

**What I want**

I have been working on the project and needed a date range picker. So used Mui date range picker for that. For the desktop, it is working wonderfully. But on Mobile view, I am getting just one month and the user need to click on the icon to go to the next month. (Image 1)[image]

[image]

I want something like this as it is on the expedia.com website. Instead horizontally all months show vertically

Is there any way I can achieve this?

**What I have used**

1. I Tried sending showMonths but I don't think there is something like that in the new DatePicker

**Code**

```
<LocalizationProvider
      dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}
      localeText={{ start: startDateLabel, end: endDateLabel }}
    >
      <DateRangePicker
        value={[startDate, endDate]}
        onChange={(newValue) => {
          handleDateChange({
            startDate: new Date(newValue[0]),
            endDate: newValue[1] ? new Date(newValue[1]) : null,
          });
        }}
        inputFormat={'DD MMM'}
        maxDate={maximumDate ? new Date(maximumDate) : new Date(moment().add('12', 'months'))}
        minDate={minimumDate ? new Date(minimumDate) : new Date()}
        renderInput={(startProps, endProps) => (
          <Box display={'flex'} gap={'10px'}>
            <StyledDatePickerTextField
              placeholder={'Add Date'}
              textfieldtype={textFieldType}
              style={{ background: 'white', borderRadius: 10, width: '100%' }}
              {...startProps}
              inputProps={{
                ...startProps.inputProps,
                placeholder: 'Add Date',
              }}
              InputLabelProps={{
                shrink: true,
              }}
            />
            <StyledDatePickerTextField
              style={{ marginLeft: 5, borderRadius: 10, background: 'white', width: '100%' }}
              {...endProps}
              textfieldtype={textFieldType}
              inputProps={{
                ...endProps.inputProps,
                placeholder: 'Add Date',
              }}
              InputLabelProps={{
                shrink: true,
              }}
            />
          </Box>
        )}
      />
    </LocalizationProvider>
```

Comment: DateRangePicker is a pro feature, and it looks like you already have access to it. There is already a mobile variant that looks exactly like what you want, called `MobileDateRangePicker`. Please see https://mui.com/x/react-date-pickers/date-range-picker/#available-components

Answer (score 1):

MUI `DateRangePicker` does not support the scrollable months feature like `Expedia`. Expedia is using a custom solution for their DateRangePicker. I have not seen any other library doing the same. The only solution for your case is creating a custom component. Sorry, `Mui` can't help you with this.

Possible solution: You can create a conditional component. Where you use Mui `DateRangePicker` for desktop and [React Infinite Calendar](http://clauderic.github.io/react-infinite-calendar/#/enhance-default-functionality/range-selection?_k=vbv0c9) range selection for mobile. It supports style customization, so can customize it to make it look like your Mui component.

I hope it helps!